# How was Sazed both of these things?

Tags: cosmere, mistborn

In *Hero of Ages*, TenSoon states that Sazed is the

> Announcer who recognizes the Hero of Ages from the prophecies.

At the end of the book, however, it is revealed that

> Sazed himself is the Hero of Ages, and takes the power of both Ruin and Preservation to remake the world.

Technically

> Sazed does recognize that he himself would become the Hero of Ages, so he has both titles.

Considering that both parts of the prophecy are quite distinct and apparently important, how could these two facts resolve this? Was it simply an author oversight?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We know that Ruin was changing and manipulating prophecy concerning the Hero of Ages. According to [this](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=727#44) excerpt from and interview, the entire concept of the Announcer was a fabrication by Ruin to reinforce the person that he wanted to set-up as the Hero of Ages.

It should also be noted that the concept of the Hero, and what they are supposed to so has been twisted by Ruin over the years as well. The original intent of the Hero was for the person to take the power, and use it to become a sort of "protector of mankind for a period of time"<sup>[2](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=727#43)</sup>. All in all the prophecy and the Hero were just tools for Ruin. There is no way for any of our characters to know what the original intent was, or if there even was one. Obviously something in them resonated with Sazed, or maybe he was just the right person in the right place at the right time.

Comment: I thought it was heavily suggested by Vin that this was actually always part of Preservation's plan to an extent.  There was a point where Vin seemed to understand once she had ascended.  Preservation didn't weaken himself, he divided himself in such a way that would allow human aspects to affect his power.  I thought that was what Vin realized as Elend died; and saw Preservation's plan.  She struggled with destroying herself; but because she was not fully of Preservation, and had just taken up the Shard,  the intent wasn't strong enough to prevent her, as it did for Preservation.